# how to replace content of div id in ViewData using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i want to access the value of viewdata["id"] in my div.

```html
<!-- Viewpage -->
<div id='@ViewData["id"]'> old contents </div>
```

```js
//Script 
var contents="div new contents are here";
$("??  .content").html(contents); // i want to replace the @ViewData["id"] contents
```

can anyone help to try out this..

thanks in advance..

regards
cooldharma06

Comment: What is the rendered HTML?

Comment: after rendering.. the result as to <div id='@ViewData["id"]'> div new contents are here </div>.. like wise i have to get..

Comment: have answered you queries do make a comment

Comment: i am trying these things dude..

Comment: if it has solved you problem mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need not to go like that

```
<div id='@ViewData['@ViewData["id"]'> old contents </div>
```

just name the div with the `ViewData` and get the value from accessing its html element through its class

e.g.

```
<div id="@ViewData["id"]" class="FieldData"> old contents </div>
```

and get value from jquery as

```
$(document).ready(function (){
var a = $(".FieldData").attr("id");
/// do other stuff here
// for changing the content within the div you can do
$(".FieldData").html("/* new content here*/");
// for changing the id of div(replacing the id of div)
$(".FieldData").attr("id","/*new id*/");   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var content="div new contents are here";
$('[id^="@ViewData"]').html(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure what is troubling you here? Irrespective of what your "id" is, all you need to do in jquery is append the id after a "#" (preferably preceded by the type of the element, like 'div'), and call the "html" method.

for that, all you require here is something like this:

```
$('div#@ViewData["id"]').html("New Content");
```

Comment: this `@ViewData["id"]`  is a c# object that is replaced by its string value on parsing; a `<div id = @ViewData["id"]'> old contents </div>` might become `<div id ='24356" > old contents </div>` and hence the solution can't solve the problem

Comment: It is not mentioned anywhere as to what the @ViewData["id"] could actually mean. Read the comment by the author:

_after rendering.. the result as to <div id='@ViewData["id"]'> div new contents are here </div>.. like wise i have to get.._

jQuery starts working, only when the "HTML" is already rendered. So I guess this is not a jQuery problem at all then.

Comment: true  this is not a jQuery problem at all! but you won't get the id as @ViewData["id"] because as soon as it is requested from the server it will be parsed and will be replaced by its value hence you cannot access the html div using this id